# JS/CSS not working while synchronous requests are being called

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I finished developing an Alfresco webscript, but I have some issues with CSS Animations and HTML attributes/innerHTML that are being updated using JS.

The webscript gets a list of users from the DB, then, when document is ready, it begins to do Synchronous (blocking) calls to retrieve all the documents for each user found, one call per user, once the call is done, it appends the response (an HTML) to a table, then goes for the next user in the array. While so, I created a loading screen using Bootstrap progress bar and a live document count, that is overwritten using innerHTML with the sum of all the documents that are being found, here is the code:

```
   function execDocsWebscript(user)
   {
       init_XMLHttpRequest();
       doRequest("url"+user, 'GET', appendRespData);
   }

   function doProgress(i)
   {
       currentProgress = (i/userArray.length)*100; //Current Progress in percentage

       var progBar = document.getElementById('progBar'); //Select the progress bar, then update attributes
       progBar.setAttribute('aria-valuenow',currentProgress);
       progBar.setAttribute('style','width:'+currentProgress+'%');
       progBar.innerHTML = Math.round(currentProgress)+'%';
       if(currentProgress == 100)
       {
           document.getElementById('progText').innerHTML = "DONE!";
       }
   }

   function appendRespData()
   {
       if (peticionHTTP.readyState == 4)
       {
           if (peticionHTTP.status == 200)
           {
               docLength = AJAXParser(peticionHTTP); //Return the no. of documents for the user
               totalDocLength += +docLength; //Sum up the total
               //Append response to HTML Table
               document.getElementById('tbody').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',peticionHTTP.responseText);
              //Update total document count in the loading screen
              document.getElementById('loadingDocuCount').innerHTML = "Documents found: "+totalDocLength; 
           }   
       }       
   }

   function showSlowly()
   {
       var i = 1;
       for (const element of userArray)
       {
           window.onload = execDocsWebscript(element); //Wait for the document to load, then do AJAX requests
           doProgress(i); //Update the progress bar
           i++;
       }
   }
```

This works fine in FireFox, the loading bar progress accordingly and the document count updates flawlessly, but this is not the case if the script is run on Chrome or Edge, the loading bar does not even start and the document count is always 0, although if you want enough time, the loading bar jumps to 100%, progText elements' innerHTML changes to "DONE!" and the script loads properly, so in the end it works, except for the animation and the live document counter.

Lastly, I have a small CSS animation, 3 jumping dots, this doesn't work either in Chrome nor Edge, I've tried adding the -webkit- tag but didn't work, here is the code:

```
<style>
.jumping-dots span {
      position: relative;
      bottom: 0px;
      animation: jump 2s infinite;
      -webkit-animation: jump 2s infinite;
    }
    
    .jumping-dots .dot-1{
      animation-delay: 200ms;
    }
    .jumping-dots .dot-2{
      animation-delay: 400ms;
    }
    .jumping-dots .dot-3{
      animation-delay: 600ms;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes jump {
      0%   {bottom: 0px;}
      20%  {bottom: 5px;}
      40%  {bottom: 0px;}
    }
    
    @-moz-keyframes jump {
      0%   {bottom: 0px;}
      20%  {bottom: 5px;}
      40%  {bottom: 0px;}
    }
    
    @-o-keyframes jump {
      0%   {bottom: 0px;}
      20%  {bottom: 5px;}
      40%  {bottom: 0px;}
    }
    
    @keyframes jump {
      0%   {bottom: 0px;}
      20%  {bottom: 5px;}
      40%  {bottom: 0px;}
    }
</style>
...
<p class="h3 text-center" id="progText">Fetching documents for each user<span class="jumping-dots">
    <span class="dot-1">.</span>
    <span class="dot-2">.</span>
    <span class="dot-3">.</span>
    </span>
</p>
```

How can I fix this? what is causing it? I believe that those two browser don't play animations while page is loading (while AJAX requests are running), but I'm not sure at all.

Here are some screenshots, this is how it looks in Edge/Chrome while it loads:
[image: Chrome/Edge bar does not appear and Document count remains 0 until document finishes loading]

And this is the one for Firefox:
[image: Firefox loading screen works as intended]

Comment: `window.onload = execDocsWebscript(element);` is nonsense but this line will still call `execDocsWebscript` so it basically works. Synchronous requests are deprecated, it sounds like Firefox will still do them while Chrome won't. The current, non-browser-freezing way is to run async requests in a for loop

Comment: Here's how to run a bunch of requests non-blocking in sequence: https://jsfiddle.net/2n38q95m/

Comment: @ChrisG Why does it make no sense? Also, as I mentioned in my post, the Sync requests are being made properly in Chrome and Edge, the thing is that the loading bar does not update its progress until it reaches 100%, same for the "Documents found"

Comment: You keep overwriting `window.onload` (with `undefined`), that's the part that doesn't make sense. You probably meant to write `window.onload = () => execDocsWebscript(element);` but while that actually makes kind of sense, it wouldn't work at all. Anyway, to fix this you need to show all relevant code, ideally as a [mre].

Comment: That was it @ChrisG ! I changed my blocking synchronous requests to the async calls in your example, seems like Chrome and Edge block any kind of JS/CSS Animation while the calls are running, but Firefox doesn't. Didn't know about the fetch() method and that you could edit HTML attributes that easy, thanks a lot! :) You may post your comment as answer so I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ChrisG for solving this, just don't use synchronous requests, otherwise the rest of the elements won't be updated until the requests are done.